# something similar to FragmentTabHost without support(v4) library

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm updating my app to use fragments instead of activites to later make a better ui for tablet. and as i have minSdk=14 i thought i could throw away support.v4 but now i want a fragment with some tabbed sub fragments. only way i found without the support library is the ActionBar tab stuff. but for tablets i want to have something like this

Left: single fragment (not changing)
Right: changing fragments where some can contain tabs

i want the tabs only visible on the right side and not on actionbar level above both sides. is there a way(thats worth the effort) to do this without support.v4  or should i redo the code i have to use the support.v4 fragment classes that i can use FragmentTabHost provided by support.v4 lib?

Comment: I suppose the support.v4 was meant to save you this kind of stress, I will advice you use the support library so as not to re-invent existing structure and spend time on meaningful developmental processes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you have a minimum SDK of `14`(and I think you're not using a `ViewPager`?!) it would make sense to use the SDK version of the fragments framework. A `FragmentTabHost` is a convenience wrapper around a `TabHost` to make working with fragments as tabs easier. I don't recall seeing an equivalent for `FragmentTabHost` in the SDK so you would have two options:

1. Use a standard `TabHost` and implement your own logic to switch the fragments when the tab changes
2. Copy the code for the `FragmentTabHost` and change it to work with the SDK version of the fragments framework. If I remember right the code for the `FragmentTabHost` is fairly simple and a copy-paste followed by changing the imports should work.

**However**, it seems you want to use the `FragmentTabHost` with nested fragments(the fragment tabs being part of another bigger fragment), in this case you need to use the fragments from the support library(along with `FragmentTabHost`) because the support for nested fragments was introduced in the SDK starting with `4.2` which means that any version between 4.0 and 4.2 will not be able to use nested fragments.

Comment: Thank you for the info about nested fragments, didn't knew that. so i think i'll stick with support library! :)